# Why is python returning an empty list when I explicitly ask it not to?

Tags: python

apologies in advance - I'm new to coding so this is probably a silly question!

I'm trying to scan a local text file (I downloaded the text from http://norvig.com/big.txt) and then read and print random lines from this file into a list.

However, I don't want to print any empty lines, just the lines that contain text.

So I've tried to use the following code:

```
import random

with open('C:\\big.txt', 'r') as f:
    while True:
        random_line_str = random.choice(f.readlines())
        random_line_lst = random_line_str.split()
        if random_line_lst != []:
            print(random_line_lst)
            break
```

So this works fine for lines that contain text. But it also occasionally spits out the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python\lib\random.py", line 253, in choice
    i = self._randbelow(len(seq))
  File "C:\Python\lib\random.py", line 230, in _randbelow
    r = getrandbits(k)          # 0 <= r < 2**k
ValueError: number of bits must be greater than zero

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/PycharmProjects/Testing/Test.py", line 5, in <module>
    random_line_str = random.choice(f.readlines())
  File "C:\Python\lib\random.py", line 255, in choice
    raise IndexError('Cannot choose from an empty sequence')
IndexError: Cannot choose from an empty sequence
```

I haven't got a clue what's going on here to be honest...

Any ideas how I can avoid this happening and only return lines that contain text?

Cheers!

Comment: You should replace the `while True` with `for line in f`

Comment: Just call deadlines once and store the resulting list, before the loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This line doesn't check if the item is an empty list, it checks if the item is in an empty list, which will always be false (meaning `item not in []` will always be true):

```
if random_line_lst not in []:
```

What you can do is since `bool([])` is False, just do:

```
if random_line_lst:
```

If you would likely to explicitly check for an empty list, use the `!=` operator.

```
if random_line_lst != []:
```

Using the above, your code then becomes:

```
import random

with open('C:\\big.txt', 'r') as f:
    while True:
        random_line_str = random.choice(f.readlines())
        random_line_lst = random_line_str.split()
        if random_line_lst:
            print(random_line_lst)
            break
```

**EDIT**

For the `random.choice`, the issue is you are repeatedly calling `random.choice` on `f.readlines()`. Readlines only returns each line on the first call, afterwards it will just return an empty sequence. `random.choice` cannot select an item from an empty sequence. A better strategy is this:

```
import random

with open('C:\\big.txt', 'r') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    while True:
        random_line_str = random.choice(lines)
        random_line_lst = random_line_str.split()
        if random_line_lst:
            print(random_line_lst)
            break
```

Or, if you can break away from randomness, use the following:

```
with open('C:\\big.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        line_lst = line.split()
        if line_lst:
            print(line_lst)
            break
```

Comment: wouldn't `if random_line_list not in []` always be `True` since no matter what `random_line_list` is, it isn't a member of the empty list ...

Comment: I changed the question slightly... that's awkward

Comment: @mgilson, check my comment. I saw the `__contains__` will always be false, not the full expression. I could clarify.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the help - I basically ended up using exactly the implementation you suggested :-)

Answer (score 2):

> print out if random_line_lst is not []

No, you are not checking for that. Rather you are checking whether list variable `random_line_lst` do not exists in `[]` which is always true since `[]` is empty and nothing exists in it. So `if random_line_lst not in []:` check is not correct.

Instead of you need to check:

```
if len(random_line_lst) > 0:
```

Or a short-cut (and better form) is to check

```
if random_line_lst:
```

Since empty lists are false.

Also, you can't call `f.readlines()` always inside loop. You need to keep that lines in a variable before the loop starts, otherwise you will get an `IndexError` next time the loop runs. The reason is in the first call of `f.readlines()` the whole file is read, and in next call file position is already at end of file, so next read will return empty list, unless you seek to zero position of the file. For your case you can just move the `readlines()` call out of loop.

```
with open('C:\\big.txt', 'r') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    while True:
        random_line_str = random.choice(lines)
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for that. You're right, the `> 0` check is exactly what I was looking for. Although I still get the exception shown above every now and then - no idea why though..

Comment: Ah! So that's why I'm getting the IndexError. Hmm, so how can I make it loop back up to read another random line if the line it first chooses is empty? I.e. keep picking a random line until it contains text...

Comment: @chewflow added a better explanation of the error. Check the edit.

Comment: You're a legend, thanks taskinoor - it worked perfectly :-)

Answer (score 2):

I feel you can make use of **strip** method in this situation, because even if the line is empty you will still have the carriage return associated to that line. So you can check for the following condition

```
line.strip() != '' #checking if the line is empty by removing the Carriage return 

with open('fdf.txt','r') as f:
     for line in f:
        if line.strip() != '' :
            print(line)
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Hey thanks, that does look neater than my attempt. Will have a look at it :-)